# Creating an array of column names in Microsoft Server SQL

Tags: sql-server, row-number, information-schema

I'm fairly new to SQL, roughly a week of using it.

I'm trying to figure out a way to create an array of column names.
Through research, I've found a way to select column names and a way to select an nth row. However, I need some way to combine these two.

Here is the following code for each:

Selecting columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tablename'
```

Selecting nth row:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Starting) NUM,
  * FROM tablename
) A
WHERE NUM = 1
```

Is there a way to combine the two so that I can get a particular value for the nth row for the first select command (column names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) Num, COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tablename'
) A
WHERE NUM = 1
```

`ORDINAL_POSITION` is nothing but "column identification number".

Comment: Omg, you're a life saver! Thanks, i've beating myself over that for the past hour.